# Ruby on Rails multiple instance for same App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just a general question:

is it possible to run the same App in development and production environment?

I got two domains the live and a test domain. The live domain should reference the production and the test domain the development version.

I think this doesn't work, right?

Comment: For sure, this should be possible. What's the problem?

Comment: It would work just fine.. Just make sure to use different ports, that's all =)

Comment: Ok thx - then something went wrong with my domain - because on both domains i get always the same environment. I am using passenger. One domain has an RailsEnv production and the other has the RailsEnv development entry.

Answer (score 0):

Using passenger, as you do, I have two virtual domains on the same host, one for staging, one for production.
My production environment has no explicit RailsEnv. `production` is the default environment, see [passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html).

My staging domain is protected by Basic Auth.

The virtual host setups of apache are (shortened):

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
          ServerName www.example.de
          ServerAlias example.de
          DocumentRoot /home/rh/office/current/public/
          <Directory /home/rh/office/current/public/>
             AllowOverride all
             Options -MultiViews
          </Directory>
       </VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.example.de
  ServerAlias www.test.example.de
  DocumentRoot /home/rh/staging_office/current/public/
  RailsEnv staging
  <Directory /home/rh/staging_office/current/public/>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "staging"
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
     Require valid-user
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```